# Does ATR0 prove existence of uncomputable well-ordering?

Tags: logic, reference-request, computability, well-orders, reverse-math

I recently came across [this webpage](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/papers/symm/node4.html) that mentions a system ATR0 + "every ordinal is recursive". I am not sure what exactly that means, but anyway I tried and failed to construct an uncomputable well-ordering within ATR0. Basically, I see no way to construct the set of programs that compute well-orderings, so it seems that in this sense ATR0 cannot prove the existence of an uncomputable well-ordering. Is this true, and if so, why? I am unable to find a reference, presumably because I do not know the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Per Andreas' comment below, there's a slight issue around what "computable well-ordering" means. There are two possible interpretations: a well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ which is not computable, or a well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ which is not *isomorphic to any* computable well-ordering. I assume that the latter is meant, since "There is a non-computable set" implies that there is a well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ which is not itself computable.

This is a situation where the term "(non)computable *ordinal*" comes into play. It's not exactly universal, but generally when people talk about a "noncomputable well-ordering" they're referring to an actual well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ which is noncomputable, whereas "noncomputable ordinal" often means a well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ not isomorphic to any computable one. For this reason, I'll talk below about ordinals rather than well-orderings, to emphasize the meaning of computability here.

---

ATR$_0$ **cannot** in fact prove the existence of a non-recursive ordinal; this is because, over ATR$_0$, the existence of a non-recursive ordinal implies the existence of [Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O).

Roughly speaking, suppose $\alpha$ is non-recursive. Then for $L_e$ a computable ordering, we have that $L_e$ is an ordinal iff there is an embedding of $L_e$ into $\alpha$ - this uses the fact that all ordinals are comparable, which is provable in ATR$_0$. Together with the usual $\Pi^1_1$ definition of ordinals, this gives a $\Delta^1_1$ definition of $\mathcal{O}$, and ATR$_0$ implies $\Delta^1_1$-CA$_0$.

So any model of ATR$_0$ + "There is a non-recursive ordinal" satisfies "$\mathcal{O}$ exists" (basically: *lightface* $\Pi^1_1$-comprehension). But the usual proof that ATR$_0$ is strictly weaker than $\Pi^1_1$-CA$_0$ builds a model of ATR$_0$ which doesn't satisfy "$\mathcal{O}$ exists." So we're done.

---

Incidentally, the standard reference on reverse math is [Simpson's book](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/chapter1.pdf); this is especially true in my opinion for results on systems stronger than ACA$_0$ ([Hirschfeldt's book](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9208#t=toc) treats systems up to and including ACA$_0$, but doesn't go past there). The material on $\beta$-models especially is relevant.

Comment: This answers the question that OP probably should have asked and perhaps intended to ask, but let me add a trivial comment about the question in the title. As soon as you have an uncomputable subset $A$ of $\omega$, you also have an uncomputable well-ordering (of order-type $\omega$), namely modify the usual ordering of $\omega$ by putting $2n+1$ before $2n$ iff $n\in A$ (and making no other changes).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Good point, I've edited.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thanks for that comment! Indeed I was thinking of ordinals with no computable presentation, but mis-stated my question since I missed the fact that there are computable ordinals with uncomputable presentation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Thanks! I had checked in SoSOA but found no explicit statement, nor mention of computable/recursive well-ordering/ordinal, so I didn't know where to look. Can you point to a specific theorem in SoSOA that essentially proves that "Kleene's O exists" requires $Π^1_1$-CA?

Comment: @user21820 Morally, this is just the fact that $\mathcal{O}$ is $\Pi^1_1$-complete, and that this relativizes: $\Pi^1_1$-CA$_0$ is equivalent to "$\mathcal{O}^X$ exists for all $X$." Specifically, the fact that "$\mathcal{O}$ exists" is unprovable in ATR$_0$ is a consequence of Lemma VII.$2.9$ (note that Simpson's HJ($X$) is really just $\mathcal{O}^X$ in disguise): if every model of ATR$_0$ thought that $\mathcal{O}$ (which is equivalent to HJ($\emptyset$)) existed, then ATR$_0$ would prove "there is a countable coded $\beta$-model" - but, Godel says this can't happen (see Corollary VII.2.8).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Thanks for that! I will have a look at it again later.